# DwfToolkit linking

Tags: linker, static-linking

I would like to to use DwfToolkit in my app, but I have problem to link it.

The code:

```
// DWF Core headers
#include "dwfcore/String.h" 
#include "dwfcore/Core.h"
#include "dwfcore/SkipList.h"
#include "dwfcore/InputStream.h"

using namespace DWFCore;

// WHIP! headers
#include "whiptk/whip_toolkit.h"

// DWF Toolkit headers
#include "dwf/Version.h"
#include "dwf/Toolkit.h"
#include "dwf/package/Manifest.h"
#include "dwf/package/EPlotSection.h"
#include "dwf/package/EModelSection.h"
using namespace DWFToolkit;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWFString path("c:\\test.dwf");
    DWFFile file(path);
    DWFPackageReader reader( file );

    return 0;
}
```

In linker options (Additional Dependencies) I added dwfcore.1.7.0.lib, dwftk_ro.7.7.0.lib, whiptk_ro.7.13.601.lib. After compile:

```
Error   902 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
public: __thiscall DWFCore::DWFString::DWFString(wchar_t const *)"
(__imp_??0DWFString@DWFCore@@QAE@PB_W@Z) referenced in function _wmain
```

When I erase line `DWFPackageReader reader( file );` from code, program is builded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking static lib add dwfcore_static in the preprocessor.